Why the arrows in path analysis in R studio is bi-directional while I was expecting to be uni-directional?
I have a column named Treatments, which contains five different treatment plots. Also, I have groundcovers within those different treatments and named them in different columns as n.gc, nn.gc, and seeded.gc (these are types of ground covers), which are in decimals. I added all of those groundcover and made a new column as total.gc within the same dataframe. I also have a soil..loss column which is the amount of soil eroded (a continuous data) through treatments with respective total.gc. I was expecting uni-directional arrows yet, I got the bi-directional arrow. I ran the code as below:
#Specify model
nov<- "
#Directional relation (path)
total.gc~n.gc+nn.gc+seeded.gc
soil..loss~total.gc
#covariances
n.gc~~nn.gc+seeded.gc
nn.gc~~seeded.gc
"

#estimate model
nov.model<- sem(nov,data=df_nov)

#summarize the result
summary(nov.model, fit.measure=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)

I was expecting to see how different treatments have different sorts of groundcover (gc) and what are the significance of those groundcovers to different applied treatmensts how they are contributing to total.gc and how total.gc is interacting with the soil..loss.
